# Android - NavigationView, Menu with icon as TexDrawable

Tags: android, menuitem, android-drawable, navigationview, android-navigationview

I am trying set the icon of item menu inside NavigationView as TextDrawable. For textDrawable im using [TextDrawable library](https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable), but once i set the icon for the menu item it only displays a black circle instead of generated drawable.

I did try my code to generate the TextDrawable outside the NavigationView and it displays want i need, but I can't manage to make it display as icon for my menu item.

To generate the TexDrawable:

```
private Drawable getLetterDrawable(String letter){
    return TextDrawable.builder()
            .beginConfig()
            .width(20)  // width in px
            .height(20) // height in px
            .endConfig()
            .buildRect(letter, Color.RED);
}
```

To set the icon:

```
        ...
        navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_drawer_users);  
        Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
        menu.add("Item text here").setIcon(getLetterDrawable("A"));
        ...
```

And this is the unexpected result:

[image: result of implementation]

**EDIT:**
When I set `R.mipmap.ic_launcher` as icon i get the android icon but also in grey color, so i can only see its border. It seems that the drawable its being "tinted" when using `menuItem.setIcon()`.

I did try to do the following, but without success:

```
        MenuInflater mi = getMenuInflater();
        mi.inflate(R.menu.menu_drawer, menu);
        menu.add("Test");
        menu.getItem(0).setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        menu.getItem(0).getIcon().clearColorFilter();
        menu.getItem(0).getIcon().invalidateSelf();
```

**Question:** How can I remove the filter and show my icon in colors?

**EDIT 2 :**  After `Andrea Basso` suggestion, I did manage to remove the tint from navigationView object, but i can't still see the letter inside the square. I only see the red square but no letter inside.

**The main problem remains:** how to put [TextDrawable](https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable) as icon on `MenuItem`?

Answer (score 1):

`NavigationView` has the method `setItemIconTintList (ColorStateList tint)`, which is what you're looking for.

A `ColorStateList` is an XML file that defines the different filters for different states. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html)'s the documentation page.

Comment: this solves the problem with tint, but i still have the main problem: how to make TextDrawable visible as icon. I can only see the red square now, no letter inside.

Comment: @Bugdr0id I don't really have experience with that library, are you sure it's not a bug of TextDrawable? I don't know, but you may try to contact the library dev.